# Use of rmvnorm and dmvnorm for two variables

Tags: r, pdf-generation

I have been trying to apply this functions but I am having some problems.
For one variable(x) I have

```
mean <- rnorm(K,mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x)) 
sigma2 <- rep(sd(x),K)

for (k in 1:K)
{
f[,k] <- dnorm(x,mu[k],sigma2[k])     ##pdf ##
}
```

I want to do the same but now I have a matrix(T) with two variables x and y 
Could somebody help me, please. I am new with R. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `mu` object is not defined (and neither are `K`, or `x`, so I'm going to assume your brain skipped a beat and that you really wanted that `mu` to be what you called `mean` that you had defined one line earlier. I'm further going make them both named `mu` since naming objects by the function that creates them is a bad idea. Your for-loop is entirely unnecessary since `dnorm` is vectorized:

```
K= 100; x <- rnorm(10) 
mu <- rnorm(K,mean=mean(x),sd=sd(x)) 
sigma2 <-sd(x)

 f <- dnorm(x,mean=mu, sd=sigma2)     ##pdf ##

 str(f)
# num [1:100] 0.39342 0.42177 0.00906 0.38493 0.29362 ...
```

So now you know how to work with dnorm. Tp make it work with a matrix by column you can do this:

```
 apply(T, 2, dnorm, mean=mu, sd=sigma2)
```

Your question title said dmvnorm but you code said dnorm, so if you wnat to use a multivariate density then you need to specify which package you are using and provide quite a  bit more detail of what the goals are.

Comment: Thanks @DWin What I wanted was to generate a bivariate normal pdf with function dmvnorm (mvtnorm package).

Comment: Then you will need two mu's and a covariance matrix and choose from among several packages that support multivariate densities. You may want to use `expand.grid` or `outer` if you want to construct a grid over which to drape a set of "dmvtnorm"'s. There must be several worked examples in the SO archives.